# How can I get rid of the effect on GitHub blog images?

Tags: github, blogs, chirpy

[blog](https://erika2852.github.io)
[repositories](https://github.com/erika2852/erika2852.github.io)
This is the link of my github blog and repositories

I used the Chirpy theme and followed the tutorial. But every post has an effect in pictures. I want to get rid of this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBXhD.gif)

I checked the tutorial again, and I also made a new repertoire from scratch. I also checked the config.yml file.